# Woocommerce Add_Rewrite_Rule Not Working For Shop Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming

I want below URL:

> https://www.example.com/shop/keyword/

to work as below URL. (below one works well.)

> https://www.example.com/shop/?search_text=keyword

I can achieve this behaviour for my `/search/` page when I add the following code to `functions.php`.

```
function my_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^search/([^/]*)?','index.php?pagename=search&search_text=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

but same code is not working for `/shop/` page.

Normal behaviour should be to lists all the products. However `/shop/` page URL shows no results.

**Edit:** It doesn't work even after permalinks are refreshed.

Comment: Goto to the Settings > permalinks and save even if you don't change anything. Try those urls then.

Comment: @SagarBahadurTamang sorry it doesn't work even with refreshed permalinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not fully understand your question, but is this what your trying to do?

[image]

If so, the WooCommerce query for the `/shop/` archive matches `post_type=product`.

Try this rewrite rule and flush your permalinks by going to Settings->Permalinks in the WordPress dashboard and then clicking the save button.

```
/**
 * Add rewrite rule from `/shop/keyword/` to `shop/?search_text=keyword`
 *
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467044/woocommerce-add-rewrite-rule-not-working-for-shop-page
 */
add_action( 'init', function (): void {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^shop/([^/]*)?',
        'index.php?post_type=product&search_text=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.